# I am trying to centre and align horizontally 3 images, but it doesn't seem to be working, whatever I try

Tags: centering

I have a general div class for the images section called 'frontpageimages'. I then have separate divs ("image1", "image2", "image3") for each image. I have set each one to display:inline, it worked for the first 2 images but the last image still isn't in the line! Here is the code:

http://codepen.io/Pea92/pen/aOvBwe

```
.image1 {
  display:inline;
}
.image2 {
  display:inline;
}
image3 {
  display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the . character from the image3 class selector, it should be:

```
.image3 {
    display:inline;
}
```

You could also make this more concise by combining these selectors:

```
.image1, .image2, .image3 {
    display:inline;
}
```